# Customize JQuery UI Autocomplete Result Selection

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the JQueryUI Autocomplete functionality.

Trying to modify the auto complete results so each result is shown in an li with left floating text and right floating text. Using this code and CSS below, I hover over does not work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a><span class='l'>" + item.name + "</a></span><span class='r'>" +  item.symbol + ":" + item.ex_short + "</span></a>")
    .appendTo( ul );
};

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item span.l {
text-align: left;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item span.r {
text-align: right;
width: 100px;
float: right;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-divider {
margin: 5px -2px 5px -2px;
height: 0;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
text-decoration: none;
padding: 2px .4em;
line-height: 1.5;
min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js looks fine, so I'd guess your css selectors aren't matching your HTML (.ui-menu, .ui-menu-item, etc.) Can you post your HTML, or a fiddle?

First thought: Should you be giving your `<li>` a class?

```
return $( "<li class='ui-menu-item'>" )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/9J9T2/